# As3 enter key should be work as tab

Tags: actionscript-3, air, textinput

I have set the tabindex of TexInput controls in my Adobe Air works fine with tab key. Now I want to do the same with the enter key. I mean when I press enter key in the TextInput, next control should be selected.

In C# we can do the same with SendKeys and as per my knowledge there is not such way in Adobe Air.

Here is my added event

```
// get key presses only when the textfield is being edited
inputText.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler);
function handler(event:KeyboardEvent){

// if the key is ENTER
if(event.charCode == 13){

   // WHAT ???
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the instance with next/previous tabIndex
2. Depending on what control you are using, either call setFocus() method on this control (if it has one), or set the focus property of the stage to this instance. Set it to null if you want to remove focus at all.